# Struct Pointer set values

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to make a constructor for struct that takes a pointer to the struct, mallocs the memory, and sets the fields. However, when I print what I believe I have set it to, I am seeing the fields as empty. I am also using C99

```
void init_student(struct student* student, char* name, int id, float gpa) {
    student = (struct student*) malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    student->name = name;
    student->id = id;
    student->gpa = gpa;
}
```

Comment: You're overwriting `student`, not modifying it.

Comment: This is not enough code to know what you are doing. What are you giving as parameters to this function? How are you using the me returned struct? Preferably make an [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning to `student`, your function parameter. Function parameters are passed by value, so the caller never sees the memory you allocated. For that, you need the *caller*'s variable to be modified, and you can achieve that by passing a pointer to *it*:

```
void init_student(struct student** student, char* name, int id, float gpa) {
    *student = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    ...
}
```

and call it as

```
struct student* student;
init_student(&student, ...);
```

Alternatively, make the pointer the return value:

```
struct student* new_student(char* name, int id, float gpa) {
  struct student* student = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
  ...
  return student;
}
```

and then

```
struct student* student = new_student(...);
```

By the way, you don't need to cast `malloc`'s result and doing so is generally discouraged in C, because it potentially hides warnings about missing `#include` directives. Also, `malloc` can fail if you're out of memory. You shouldn't try to dereference the returned null pointer in that case.

Comment: ..or just return the pointer to the allocated memory from the function.

Comment: @haccks Indeed, I was just editing that in when you posted your comment. :)